# Open source Calendar View

Tags: android, calendar

I'm looking for a Calendar View in which I will be able to create events at date level and which has ability to show all events (task) in the form of a list. I found [Extended Calendar View](https://github.com/tyczj/ExtendedCalendarView) which allows to create at the hourly level but doesn't have ability to save the events or show the list of events. Can anyone suggest some calendar view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a Calender library you can dig through. Hope it helps.
https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid